# How to get unique records SQL SERVER after join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The result Im getting after joining tables

| MovieId | MovieName | Actor Name | ProducerName | Date | Plot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hulk | abe | don | 2021-09-24 | smash |
| 1 | hulk | link | don | 2021-09-24 | smash |
| 1 | hulk | abe | kal | 2021-09-24 | smash |
| 1 | hulk | link | kal | 2021-09-24 | smash |

How to get the result as follows in SQL Server

| MovieId | MovieName | ActorName | ProducerName | Date | Plot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hulk | abe,link | don,kal | 2021-09-24 | smash |

Tables as follows

**Producer table**

| ProducerId | ProducerName | DOB | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | don | 2021-09-24 | don productions |
| 3 | kal | 2021-09-24 | kal productions |

**Actor table**

| Actor Id | ActorName | DOB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | abe | 2021-09-24 |
| 4 | link | 2021-09-24 |

**Movie table**

| Movie Id | MovieName | ReleaseDate | Plot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hulk | 2021-09-24 | hulk smash |

**Actor Movie**

| Id | MovieId | ActorId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |

**Producer Movie**

| Id | MovieId | ActorId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

Query I have used

```
Select Movie.MovieId, (Movie.MovieName),ActorName,ProducerName,ReleaseDate,Plot from Movie 
inner Join ActorMovie on Movie.MovieId = ActorMovie.MovieId 
inner join ProducerMovie on Movie.MovieId = ProducerMovie.MovieId
inner join Actor on ActorMovie.ActorId = Actor.ActorId
inner join Producer on ProducerMovie.ProducerId = Producer.ProducerId
```

Comment: Please post those table's sample data and the query you have.

Comment: @Mova I have added the tables and data

Comment: The question is already closed, I am unable to post an answer.

Comment: @nihar can you put this in a http://sqlfiddle.com/